# ember-simple-auth and IE

Tags: authentication, ember.js

I've recently upgrated to 0.1.1 from 0.13, and after a few hiccups it seems to be working. I can login to my app using most browsers (IE9-11, FF, Chrome) when running in development on my local machine.

When I deploy to a staging environment on heroku I'm seeing some strange behaviour on IE (9-11). Basically it looks like the bearer token is never being set. After looking through the code for ember-simple-auth I can see that it uses the ajax prefilter function to add the bearer token prior to a call back to the server. When I look in the Network tools on IE the token isn't there, so I always receive a 401 and am transitioned back to the index page.

I can see the login call to retrieve the token working, it just is never added to any subsequent calls.

I've looked for bugs with jQuery, IE and prefilter but haven't turned anything up. The code on staging is minified and concatenated, which makes debugging somewhat problematic.

Any suggestions on what to try next much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tracked this down to an issue with HTTPS and ports in ember-simple-auth. Details can be found in [this](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/issues/84) issue.